# html,css.php? help how output my form subissions into webpage instead of text file?

Tags: php, html, css

help i have bit knowledge in html,css but
im kinda new to php forms,database,etc stuffs

my php is working well, when user click submit all forms goes to carlist.txt

**but i want it output it through webpage html instead of .txt so i can view it online**
how i can able to do that?

and i dont want the users sees their submisions... only me can view it

html :

```
<html>
    <form action"awesome.php" method=get>

    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    blah.. blahh.
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
      </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    etc. etc. blah blah
</html>
```

awesome.php:

```
<?php
header("Location: thanksforsubmiting.html");
$handle = fopen("carslist.txt", "a");
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

thanksforsubmitting.html:

```
<html>
<title>thank you</title>
<h1> <font color=red> 
thank you for submission </h1></font>

</html>
```

please be gentle to me im kinda newbie :)) TIA

Comment: What uses sees is one flow, and what you see is another. If it's not you who is submitting the form, you can't see the post-page. You need to collect your user submissions elsewhere and open them afterwards, like you're doing with that txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at awesome.php write following code

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $firstName = $_GET['firstname'];
    $car = $_GET['cars'];
    echo $firstname;
    echo $car;
}
```

Comment: how about to show the thanksforsubmitting.html i want a thanks webpage redirect after that how to do that?

Comment: i dont want the users sees their submisions... only me can view it..  so i seperate it and show a thanks webpage how to add that?

Comment: within the if statement after getting variables and echoing them, redirect your page to whatever url u want.e.g. header("Location: thanksforsubmitting.php");

Comment: thanks.. can you do an example codes? im sorry im really newbie in php

Comment: yea sure. i mean can you do example of redirecting like you just said?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
    echo $value."<br />";
}
?>
```

If you want view it online create another page with something like this

```
$file = file_get_contents('carlist.txt');
$rows = explode("\n", $file);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i dont want the users sees their submisions... only me can view it.. so i seperate it and redirect a thanks webpage how to add that?

Comment: can you make example i cant understand sorry im really newbie in php. where do i add the another code?

Answer (score 0):

ok here is an example code you want. i'm using just 2 files form.php and form1.php. Form.php contains:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    header("Location:form1.php");
}
?>
<form name="test" action="" method="post">
<label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname"/>
<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

and form1.php contains following statement:

```
<?php
echo "Form Submitted!";
?>
```

On submition form will stay on the same page since action is null in form. In the if statement it will be redirected!